# How can I add a variable to a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hi all I am new to batch files and struggling.I am using sql server 2008

I have created a single batch file that execute other batch files + sql scripts. 
I would like to use variables how can I do that?
I would like to set the path as a variable.
I could have more than one path depending on the script's location.

```
:On Error exit 

 CALL C:\mypath\Scripts\ExecSqlScripts.bat
 CALL C:\mypath\Scripts\ExecSqlScriptsTwo.bat

 SQLCMD -S (Local) -i C:\mypath\Scripts\InsertUsernameTwo.sql
 SQLCMD -S (Local) -i C:\mypath\Scripts\InsertUsernameThree.sql
 SQLCMD -S (Local) -i C:\mypath\Scripts\InsertUsernameFour.sql
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `set` command - http://www.computerhope.com/sethlp.htm

```
:On Error exit 

set thePath=C:\mypath\Scripts

 CALL %thePath%\ExecSqlScripts.bat
 CALL %thePath%\ExecSqlScriptsTwo.bat

 SQLCMD -S (Local) -i %thePath%\InsertUsernameTwo.sql
 SQLCMD -S (Local) -i %thePath%\InsertUsernameThree.sql
 SQLCMD -S (Local) -i %thePath%\InsertUsernameFour.sql
```

The 
set `thePath=C:\mypath\Scripts` can be called from outside the batch file too.

Another solution to avoiding repetitive code to use the for command.

```
for %%f in (ExecSqlScripts ExecSqlScriptsTwo) do call %%f.bat
```

This does the equivalent of the
     CALL %thePath%\ExecSqlScripts.bat
     CALL %thePath%\ExecSqlScriptsTwo.bat

```
for %%f in (InsertUsernameTwo InsertUsernameThree InsertUsernameFour) do call SQLCMD -S (Local) -i %thePath%\%%f.sql
```

This does the equivalent of the

```
 SQLCMD -S (Local) -i %thePath%\InsertUsernameTwo.sql
 SQLCMD -S (Local) -i %thePath%\InsertUsernameThree.sql
 SQLCMD -S (Local) -i %thePath%\InsertUsernameFour.sql
```

Comment: That worked a treat.Regarding your better solution I dont understand it . I see you are looping but %%f confused me.Would it be ok to explain it a bit.

Comment: There are many good questions on the for command : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=for+loop+batch